# Why does MEGAsync need my password?

Tags: macos, login, authentication

I have downloaded the MEGAsync app (because MEGA won't let me download in Firefox), and whenever I launch it, I get a password prompt with no stated reason:
[image]

Why does MEGAsync need my password?

MEGAsync is a desktop app made by MEGA, which uploads and downloads files to and from MEGA's cloud platform. I am trying to use it to download a large file, because MEGA won't let you download large files in Firefox.

macOS Sierra

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is basically a [customer support question](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y) which should be addressed to the vendor/software provider first.

Comment: @nohillside MEGA didn't tell me what it needed it for when I asked them, only that it was required. I also don't trust them, which is why I asked this here.

Comment: I‘m not sure the tool is widely known, please add some details about it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MEGASync requires an admin password because it installs a Finder plugin.